# Laravel New Project_Name command not working after updating laravel 6

Tags: laravel

[Screenshot of CMD](https://i.stack.imgur.com/whh3x.png)

laravel cmd command : laravel new blog 
not working. its showing an error, I have added picture of cmd, kindly check and give me solution

Comment: Please post your code and error text as formatted text, not as linked images.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to place Composer's system-wide vendor bin directory in your $PATH so the laravel executable can be located by your system. This directory exists in different locations based on your operating system; however, some common locations include:

> macOS and GNU / Linux Distributions: $HOME/.config/composer/vendor/bin
>
> Windows: %USERPROFILE%\AppData\Roaming\Composer\vendor\bin

Reference the docs

https://laravel.com/docs/6.x

youtube

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eD4yMI-IR8g

Laracasts

https://laracasts.com/series/laravel-6-from-scratch/episodes/3